# Meaning of characters and symbols of T-SQL syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, sql-update, special-characters

Below is the syntax for the UPDATE statement in SQL Server.  I guess in my past, I understood some of the symbols/characters in syntax definitions, but never really truly understood all of the symbols/characters mean with SQL syntax.  Can someone help me understand what the following mean in the syntax definition below?

1. `[ ]`
2. `{ }`
3. `[...n]`
4. `[,...n]`
5. `<some_text>`
6. `@token`
7. `::=`
8. `.`
9. `|`
10. `.WRITE`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [...n] ]
UPDATE 
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
    { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited 
         [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]
      }
      | @table_variable    
    }
    SET
        { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }
          | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression
                                | field_name = expression }
                                | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] )
                              }
          }
          | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }
          | @variable = expression
          | @variable = column = expression
          | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
          | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
          | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
        } [ ,...n ] 

    [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]
    [ FROM{ <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ WHERE { <search_condition> 
            | { [ CURRENT OF 
                  { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name } 
                      | cursor_variable_name 
                  } 
                ]
              }
            } 
    ] 
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]
[ ; ]

<object> ::=
{ 
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name . 
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] . 
    | schema_name .
    ]
    table_or_view_name}
```

Comment: There's a link at the top of the page you linked that explains the [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx). Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: From the page that you referenced 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx

Comment: This looks like [Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) or some derivative of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SQL Server Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions topic in the Books Online (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx):

`UPPERCASE` Transact-SQL keywords.

`italic` User-supplied parameters of Transact-SQL syntax.

`bold` Database names, table names, column names, index names, stored procedures, utilities, data type names, and text that must be typed exactly as shown.

`underline` Indicates the default value applied when the clause that contains the underlined value is omitted from the statement.

`| (vertical bar)` Separates syntax items enclosed in brackets or braces. You can use only one of the items.

`[ ] (brackets)` Optional syntax items. Do not type the brackets.

`{ } (braces)` Required syntax items. Do not type the braces.

`[,...n]` Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The occurrences are separated by commas.

`[...n]` Indicates the preceding item can be repeated n number of times. The occurrences are separated by blanks.

`;` Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version.

`<label> ::=` The name for a block of syntax. This convention is used to group and label sections of lengthy syntax or a unit of syntax that can be used in more than one location within a statement. Each location in which the block of syntax can be used is indicated with the label enclosed in chevrons: .

A set is a collection of expressions, for example ; and a list is a collection of sets, for example .

Comment: Do you know what significance "@var" has versus var (without @) in a function?  Also do you know the difference between a <label> (without ::=) and one without <> (ie: expression)?

Comment: @MacGyver, if I understand your question correctly, `var` (without the `@`) would be interpreted as an identifier (e.g. column name).  When you see <label> without `::=`, it is indicates where a block of code would be inserted with separately defined syntax.  The syntax of the code block is detailed by `<label> ::'`.  For example <Table_Hint_Limited> is described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx where you will see `<Table_Hint_Limited> ::=`.  If this comment doesn't help, please update your question with more context.

Comment: Makes perfect sense!  Thanks!